# what is token hex API and transaction abi?

Tags: transactions, abi

What is token hex API and transaction abi in the [abieos repo](https://github.com/EOSIO/abieos)? Can ABI be generated for any transaction on the EOS block chain? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to [this file](https://github.com/EOSIO/abieos/blob/master/src/test.cpp), the two are as follows:

**[tokenHexApi](https://github.com/EOSIO/abieos/blob/master/src/test.cpp#L8-L21)**: an array of characters representing the hexadecimal representation of a contract ABI.

```
const char tokenHexApi[] = "0e656f73696f3a3a6162692f312e30010c6163636f756e745f6e616d65046e61"
                           "6d6505087472616e7366657200040466726f6d0c6163636f756e745f6e616d65"
                           "02746f0c6163636f756e745f6e616d65087175616e7469747905617373657404"
                           "6d656d6f06737472696e67066372656174650002066973737565720c6163636f"
                           "756e745f6e616d650e6d6178696d756d5f737570706c79056173736574056973"
                           "737565000302746f0c6163636f756e745f6e616d65087175616e746974790561"
                           "73736574046d656d6f06737472696e67076163636f756e7400010762616c616e"
                           "63650561737365740e63757272656e63795f7374617473000306737570706c79"
                           "0561737365740a6d61785f737570706c79056173736574066973737565720c61"
                           "63636f756e745f6e616d6503000000572d3ccdcd087472616e73666572000000"
                           "000000a531760569737375650000000000a86cd4450663726561746500020000"
                           "00384f4d113203693634010863757272656e6379010675696e74363407616363"
                           "6f756e740000000000904dc603693634010863757272656e6379010675696e74"
                           "36340e63757272656e63795f7374617473000000";
```

If we do some conversion from hex to ASCII, we get something like this:

```
eosio::abi/1.0??account_name?name??transfer???from?account_name?to?account_name?quantity?asset?memo?string?create???issuer?account_name?maximum_supply?asset?issue???to?account_name?quantity?asset?memo?string?account???balance?asset?currency_stats???supply?asset?max_supply?asset?issuer?account_name????W-<???transfer???????1v?issue??????l?E?create?????8OM?2?i64??currency??uint64?account??????M??i64??currency??uint64?currency_stats????
```

So this is just a typical contract ABI in hex encoding.

Similarly, **[transactionAbi](https://github.com/EOSIO/abieos/blob/master/src/test.cpp#L23)** is an ABI is JSON.

They are used in `abieos_set_abi_hex()` and `abieos_set_abi()` functions in order to upload the ABI to the blockchain (similar to `cleos set abi`).

> Can ABI be generated for any transaction on the EOS block chain?

These are `set abi` transactions that push an ABI to the chain. ABIs are generated for contracts, and transactions deliver them to the blockchain.

Comment: thanks but how was ABI converted to JSON? and by contract ABI do you mean the contract.abi file which is generated using eosiocpp -g contract.abi contract.cpp?

Comment: "how was ABI converted to JSON?" <- you mean hex to JSON to interface with the ABI? hex doesn't need to be converted to JSON; JSON needs to be converted to binary. hex is converted to binary as well [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/abieos/blob/9d487a5bca0a3eb04b4fddf0ad5521f7789bb36f/src/abieos.cpp#L128) and yes, I mean contract.abi-type of abi

Comment: are the contents of contract.abi file in json format?

Comment: all the ones i've seen have been json, yes

Comment: does that mean tokenHexApi[] is hexadecimal representation of transactionAbi[] ?

Comment: they both represent an abi, but they use different encodings to represent information. in the end, they're both binary, but they have different intermediate representations. in ASCII, a character represents an octet and in hex one character is 4 bits

Comment: do they both represent the same abi ?

Comment: they're probably different. they're just testing it works